# Explicit estimates for $N(T,\chi)$ (not $N(T,\chi)+N(T,\overline{\chi})$)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $N(T,\chi)$ denote the number of zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ with imaginary part between $0$ and $T$, with any zero with imaginary part equal to $T$ or to $0$ (not that the latter kind really exists) counting as half a zero. Here I am following the convention in Montgomery-Vaughan, rather than that in part of the literature, where $N(T,\chi)$ means what I would call $N(T,\chi) + N(T,\overline{\chi})$.

The explicit literature generally (McCurley, Trudgian, Bennett-Martin-O'Bryant-Rechnitzer...) generally bounds $N(T,\chi) + N(T,\overline{\chi})$. The question is: what kind of explicit bounds we can extract from their proofs for $N(T,\chi)$?

---

The first step is easy: we can express $N(T,\chi)$ as $\text{main term} + S(T,\chi)-S(0,\chi)$, as in Montgomery-Vaughan, Thm. 14.5, where $S(T,\chi) = \frac{1}{\pi} \arg L(1/2+iT,\chi)$. One would then decompose
$$S(T,\chi)-S(0,\chi) = \frac{1}{\pi} \left(\arg L(\sigma+i T,\chi)|_{\sigma=\sigma_0}^{1/2} +  \arg L(\sigma_0+i t,\chi)|_{t=0}^T + 
\arg L(\sigma,\chi)|_{\sigma=1/2}^{\sigma_0}\right)$$
for some $\sigma_0>1$ of our choice. The literature gives the bound $2 \log \zeta(\sigma_0)$ on $\left|\arg L(\sigma_0+it)|_{t=-T}^T\right|$. The reason is a mystery to me -- it is obvious that $2 \sum_p \arcsin p^{-\sigma}$ is a tighter upper bound on $\left|\arg L(\sigma_0+it)|_{t=-T}^T\right|$ (and it is easy to compute). I do not know how to do better than $2 \sum_p \arcsin p^{-\sigma}$ as an upper bound on
$\left|\arg L(\sigma_0+it)|_{t=0}^T\right|$, and suspect one cannot, in general, as $t$
and $\chi$ could conspire.

The bulk of the explicit literature deals with bounding $\arg L(\sigma+i T,\chi)|_{\sigma=\sigma_0}^{1/2}$. Is there a better bound on $\arg L(\sigma,\chi)|_{\sigma=1/2}^{\sigma_0}$ than what one would get just by setting $T=0$?

Comment: Important self-correction: I should have said $\arcsin$, not $\arctan$. You still get a tighter upper bound.

Comment: And yes, by the linear independence of $\pi$ and $\log 2, \log 3,\dotsc,\log p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $t$ and $\chi$ can conspire, and so the bound is tight, for $t$ and $\chi$ unbounded. (As @juan points out below - use Kronecker's theorem.)

Answer (score 3):

For the first question about $2\log\zeta(\sigma_0)|$, I think the reasoning is this:

For $\sigma>2$ we have
$$|L(s,\chi)-1|\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^\sigma}=\zeta(\sigma)-1<1.$$
Hence $\log L(s,\chi)$ can be defined by the power series
$$\log L(s,\chi)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}(1-L(s,\chi))^k$$
In particular  $|\Im \log L(2+it,\chi)|<\pi/2$ and coincide with $\arg(L(2+it,\chi))$. Also this is equal to
$$\log L(2+it)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^{2+it}}$$
It follows that
$$|\arg L(2+it)|\le |\log L(2+it)|\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\log\zeta(2).$$
Now it follows that
$$|\arg L(2+it,\chi)-\arg L(2,\chi)|\le 2\log\zeta(2).$$

Comment: Oh, I know how to derive *that* - I was just pointing out that (a) one can easily do better, (b) I don't know how to get rid of the factor of $2$ (and one most likely can't).

Comment: The mystery is why people don't give a better bound :).

Comment: @Helfgott I misunderstood you, I was surprised that you were unaware of this. I think the factor 2 can not be eliminated, perhaps using Kronecker's theorem we can prove this.

Comment: That's also my impression.